# Is it possible to release and lock a mutex between function invocations?

Tags: rust, synchronization, mutex

I am attempting to create a simple event loop with Mio. Every event invokes an associated callback depending on the `Token` of the event. The event loop runs on a separate thread to the rest of the code.

Events can be registered via the `register` function, however in order to register the event it must add it to the same `HashMap` of callbacks (and access the same Mio `Poll` struct) that the event loop is iterating.

The issue is that callbacks themselves may register events, in this case it is impossible to take the mutex as the event loop has the mutex. Is it possible to somehow drop the `Mutex` in the `start()` function whilst the callback is being invoked? Although, this does not seem performant.

Is there a better way to handle this in Rust?

```
use mio::event::Event;
use mio::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
use mio::{event, Events, Interest, Poll, Token};
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread::JoinHandle;
use std::{io, thread};

pub trait HookCb: Send {
    fn call(&self, event: &Event);
}

impl<F: Send> HookCb for F
where
    F: Fn(&Event),
{
    fn call(&self, event: &Event) {
        self(event)
    }
}

struct EventLoopInner {
    handlers: HashMap<Token, Box<dyn HookCb>>,
    poll: Poll,
}

pub struct EventLoop {
    inner: Mutex<EventLoopInner>,
}

impl EventLoop {
    pub fn new() -> io::Result<Self> {
        Ok(Self {
            inner: Mutex::new(EventLoopInner {
                handlers: HashMap::new(),
                poll: Poll::new()?,
            }),
        })
    }

    pub fn start(&self) -> io::Result<()> {
        let mut events = Events::with_capacity(1024);

        let inner = &mut *self.inner.lock().unwrap(); // Inner mutex taken
        loop {
            inner.poll.poll(&mut events, None)?;
            for event in events.iter() {
                match event.token() {
                    Token(v) => {
                        if let Some(cb) = inner.handlers.get(&Token(v)) {
                            // TODO release the inner mutex before here so that the callback can invoke register
                            cb.call(event)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    pub fn register<S>(
        &self,
        source: &mut S,
        interest: Interest,
        cb: impl HookCb + 'static,
    ) -> io::Result<Token>
    where
        S: event::Source + std::marker::Send,
    {
        let mut inner = self.inner.lock().unwrap(); // Cannot get this lock after start() has been invoked
        let token = Token(inner.handlers.len());
        inner.poll.registry().register(source, token, interest)?;
        inner.handlers.insert(token, Box::new(cb));
        Ok(token)
    }
}

struct ServerConn {
    listener: Option<TcpListener>,
    connections: HashMap<Token, TcpStream>,
}

struct Server {
    eventloop: Arc<EventLoop>,
    thread: Option<JoinHandle<()>>,
    conn: Arc<Mutex<ServerConn>>,
}

impl Server {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            eventloop: Arc::new(EventLoop::new().unwrap()),
            thread: None,
            conn: Arc::new(Mutex::new(ServerConn {
                listener: None,
                connections: HashMap::new(),
            })),
        }
    }

    pub fn listen(&mut self, addr: &str) {
        {
            let mut conn = self.conn.lock().unwrap();
            conn.listener = Some(TcpListener::bind(addr.parse().unwrap()).unwrap());

            let cb_conn = Arc::clone(&self.conn);
            let cb_eventloop = Arc::clone(&self.eventloop);

            self.eventloop
                .register(
                    conn.listener.as_mut().unwrap(),
                    Interest::READABLE,
                    move |e: &Event| {
                        Self::accept_cb(e, &cb_conn, &cb_eventloop);
                    },
                )
                .unwrap();
        } // Unlock conn

        let t_eventloop = Arc::clone(&self.eventloop);
        self.thread = Some(thread::spawn(move || {
            t_eventloop.start().unwrap();
        }));

        self.thread.take().unwrap().join().unwrap(); // Temp fix to block main thread so application does not exit
    }

    fn accept_cb(_e: &Event, conn: &Arc<Mutex<ServerConn>>, evloop: &Arc<EventLoop>) {
        let mut conn_lock = conn.lock().unwrap();
        loop {
            let (mut stream, addr) = match conn_lock.listener.as_ref().unwrap().accept() {
                Ok((stream, addr)) => (stream, addr),
                Err(_) => return,
            };
            println!("Accepted connection from: {}", addr);

            // TODO can this clone be avoided?
            let cb_conn = Arc::clone(conn);
            let cb_evloop = Arc::clone(evloop);
            let token = evloop
                .register(
                    &mut stream,
                    Interest::READABLE.add(Interest::WRITABLE),
                    move |e: &Event| {
                        Self::conn_cb(e, &cb_conn, &cb_evloop);
                    },
                )
                .unwrap();
            conn_lock.connections.insert(token, stream);
        }
    }

    pub fn conn_cb(e: &Event, conn: &Arc<Mutex<ServerConn>>, _evloop: &Arc<EventLoop>) {
        let conn_lock = conn.lock().unwrap();

        let mut _connection = conn_lock.connections.get(&e.token()).unwrap();
        if e.is_writable() {
            // TODO write logic -- connection.write(b"Hello World!\n").unwrap();
            // TODO evloop.reregister(&mut connection, event.token(), Interest::READABLE)?
        }
        if e.is_readable() {
            // TODO read logic -- connection.read(&mut received_data);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut s = Server::new();
    s.listen("127.0.0.1:8000");
}
```

Comment: Why not pass in `&mut inner` as an argument? (you could also `mem::drop` the mutex before the callback then relock it but that's... ugly)

Comment: I had not thought of that however as the callback is stored in the same hashmap that it is modifying I get the error: cannot borrow as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable